# Export ANT landscape as heightmap

Tags: export

I found this *old* question by "omuverde" on blenderartists[1]

> It's there a way to export a ANT Landscape generated terrain from Blender to a heightmap?  I saw a tutorial that did it by positioning the camera above the terrain and rendering the heightmap but i'd like a more elegant way of doing this.
>
> So, is there a way or am I going to have to write a script to sort verts from the mesh in the right order?

I repost it here because the question was never answered, and the suggested method (render the heightmap as an image) may have issues with the choice of lightsource. Also It is preferred that the image is exported in linear colorspace.

[1] http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?115406-ANT-Landscape-to-Heightmap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be achieved by baking the height of a mesh.

Before you start, make sure that the origin of the object is beneath or at the lowest point of the mesh, preferably the latter. Negative values do not go well with images.
Go to the *UV/Image Editor* and create a new image

[image]

Go to the *3D view*, select your mesh, go to *edit mode*, select all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd>, go to *orthographic view* by pressing <kbd>numpad 5</kbd> and *top view* by pressing <kbd>numpad 7</kbd>.
Press <kbd>U</kbd> and click *Project From View (Bounds)*

[image]

Go back to *Object Mode*, go to the *node editor* add a new material for the mesh. Add a *Texture Coordinate* node, a *Separate XYZ* node and a *Math* node. Connect the *Object* output from the *Texture Coordinate* node to the *Vector* input of the *Separate XYZ* node, the *Z* output of the *Separate XYZ* node to the upper input of the *Math* node and the output of the *Math* node to the *Color* input of the *Diffuse* node. Change the operation mode of the *Math* node to *Power* and the bottom value to 2.

Add an *Image Texture* node, select the just created image in it, but do not connect it to any other node.

The *Node Editor* should look like this:
[image]

Make sure you have the *Image Texture* node selected, go in the *Properties Panel* to the *Render* tab. Go to the *Bake* options, change *Bake Type* to *Diffuse Color* and click *Bake*.

[image]

You can now find the height map in the *UV/Image Editor* by selecting the image you created at the start. Do not forget to save the height map by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>.

[image]

Note that this method is not perfect, a mesh created using this height map will not be completely identical to the original mesh.

Comment: Why taking the square?

Comment: The square of the height. Has that to do with gamma correction?

Comment: It has something to do with the way color data is stored. Minutephysics explains it a bit in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw. I tested multiple methods, and taking the square gets the best result. I am not sure why, but it works. Compare these two pictures: https://snapr.pw/i/0b9059b0e5.png (without taking the square) and https://snapr.pw/i/bbc94fb546.png (with taking the square)

Comment: Ok so it has to do with gamma correction. Then squaring is not precisely correct. I need to know if I can save a linear image from blender or not. See also https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Color_Management